# Getting error while updating url(Mandatory field is null) field by using curl command

Tags: json, curl

```
curl -X PUT "https://Bangladesh.bank.cloud.ibm.com/api/notificationChannels/333997" -H "Authorization: Bearer $bearer_token" -H "InstanceID: <instanceID>" -H "content-type: application/json" -d @my.json|jq '.'

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "reason": "Mandatory field is null",
      "message": "Field notificationChannel cannot be null",
      "field": "notificationChannel"
```

Content of my.json file is:
{"notificationChannels":[{"id":333997,"version":8,"createdOn":1435473261117,"modifiedOn":1411142125673,"teamId":36050,"type":"EMAIL","enabled":false,"sendTestNotification":false,"name":"Zarqavi","options":{"emailRecipients":["Abdul.zarqavi@ibm.com"],"notifyOnOk":true,"notifyOnResolve":true,"allowInsecureConnections":false}}]}

Comment: found solution for this, input file that we supplied (@my.json) is not formatted with |jq '.'